# django settings error (DB Engine) when I moved all of my apps to "apps" directory

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

I changed the traditional django layout, and decided to put all of my apps to `apps` directory.

the initial layout is something like this:

```
Project/
   apps/
       myapp/
          __init__.py
   tests/
       __init__.py
   setting.py
   urls.py
   wsgi.py

manage.py
```

within `settings.py` I just set the normal engine and name as well :

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'dev.db'),
```

and finally within the `INSTALLED_APPS`, I've tried both `Project.apps.myapp` and `apps.myapp`, with no success.

Here is the engine error that I get:

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
>   value. Check settings documentation for more details.

There should be a problem with my new layout ... I've seen some solutions, but none of them were supposed such django layout ...

**P.S.** as you can see, I'm using django 1.4+ layout

---

**Solved**

**For The Record 1**: If you decide to change the default layout, be careful about the `settings.py`. I added a `settings` directory, beside of `settings.py` and that was the main source of the problem ..  I still don't know how to handle such settings. say, if I'd like to have different settings for **production**, **development** and **testing** machines ..

**For The Record 2**: I found Daniel Greenfeld's settings layout very useful(@pydanny). 
Here is the [link to its github](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/master/project_name/project_name/settings) (derived form the 'Two scoops of django' book)

Comment: Has the apps directory got an ``__init__.py`` it needs to be a python module too :)

Comment: Yes .. every directory has its own `__init__.py`. I even put `from myapp import *` into `__init__.py` .. it was not useful ..

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your followup - how to have different settings for production, development and testing:

check out how it's done in this django skeleton project:

http://amccloud.com/post/14689947527/django-1-4-custom-project-template

even though it's for django 1.4 it's still useful (only missing the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting from django 1.5)

it has settings.py and local_settings.py (local_settings.py should be different on each machine)

Comment: thanks for the link.. Although its structure is different from mine, I will take a look at it for some inspirations..